Order of warning output in clang is different for each compilation
When compiling with clang, I noticed that the order of the warning output was different for each compilation.
For example, The output was as follows
foo.c:473:20: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'short' [-Wimplicit-int-conversion]
    b2 = s2 ;
                 ~ ^~~~~~~~~
foo.c:360:14: warning: variable 's1' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    long            s1 = 0 ;
                    ^
foo.:353:21: warning: variable 'l2' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    long            l2 = 0 ;
                    ^
foo.c:352:21: warning: variable 'l1' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    long            l1 = 0 ;

or,
foo.c:473:20: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'short' [-Wimplicit-int-conversion]
    b2 = s2 ;
                 ~ ^~~~~~~~~
foo.c:352:21: warning: variable 'l1' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    long            l1 = 0 ;
                    ^
foo.c:360:14: warning: variable 's1' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    long            s1 = 0 ;
                    ^
foo.c:353:21: warning: variable 'l2' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    long            l2 = 0 ;
                    ^

I always want to ensure that the order is the same.

Why would that be important? If you must have it in a particular format you could always parse the output and sort it however you like.

This sounds like an XY problem to me. Why do you need a defined order?

The order doesn't really matter, but still, it's strange that the compilation of the same source file with the same compiler and same compiler flags (BTW is this actually the case?) doesn't give the same diagnostic output each time.

Our software project are very large and many programmers are making improvements and modifications on a daily basis. The software is written for old C compiler. Now, we try to change to clang to support new processors. Then a number of warnings were output. The code should be modified to suppress warnings, but it is so large that I gave up on the modification. So we are trying to compare the build logs to make sure they are the same as after the modification. Therefore, it is difficult for people to determine if the order is different.

I think that clang is processing in multi-threading so the order may be different. I believe that this is the case. If so, there might be an option to make it single threaded, but I didn't see it.

Or sort the findings and compare the result. -- Anyway, correcting potential errors in legacy software does almost always pay. Else you keep the technical debt.

This seems like a fine question in principle, but there's barely any information here to use to try to investigate it.  Can you make a minimal reproducer?  What platform are you running on?  How many CPU cores?  What version of Clang?  Can you at least show the code that provoked these warnings?
